# "When I can not sleep" vs "When I do not sleep"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I need to correct the following sentence without making it a consequences.

> When I can not sleep at night I get grumpy the whole day.

I've corrected it below but somehow it's the word "get" that seems a little off here:

> When I do not sleep at night, I get grumpy the whole day.

Comment: Welcome to our community! To keep the quality of the questions high, we do not answer proofreading requests. Unfortunately, the way your question is currently formulated, raises the alarms of being such question. To make it on-topic, you need to tell us what confuses you. For more info, please see [Alternative websites for proofreading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/) and [Details, please!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/).

Comment: What is the meaning of "without making it a consequences"? I don't see how, since getting grumpy is a consequence of not sleeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say, "When I *cannot* sleep at night, I *am* grumpy the whole day."  Notice that "cannot" is one word.

Using your wording, you can say, "When I do not sleep at night, I am grumpy the whole day."  However, your sentence implies that you did not sleep at all during the night.  Using "cannot" implies that you likely got some sleep but not much.  Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 However, "[Both *cannot* and *can not* are acceptable spellings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/cannot-or-can-not)" (though "but the first is much more usual").

Answer (score 1):

> When I **can not** sleep at night I get grumpy the whole *next* day.

This means you tried to sleep but couldn't. Maybe you were upset about something, or there were loud noises.

> When I **do not** sleep at night I get grumpy the whole *next* day.

This means you intentionally did not sleep, such as working all night or studying for an exam.

Beyond that, when you use *get grumpy*, it indicates a state change (not grumpy --> grumpy). But that does not logically occur all day (the whole day). So I would use a form of *to be* to indicate a continuous state. Or dump the continuous state (whole day).

> When I can/do not sleep at night, I **get** grumpy the *next* day.

or

> When I can/do not sleep at night, I **am** grumpy the whole (next) day.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about consequences why don't you just use If?

> If I don't sleep at night, I get grumpy the whole day.

although it is just fine saying

> When I don't sleep at night, I get grumpy the whole day.

Comment: It is not just fine to write that.  You should always use upper case I, not lower case i.

Comment: Thanks hey. I'm only allowed to change one or two words and keep the original structure

Comment: "get" marks a (grammatically) perfected status/aspect and thus cannot be used with a duration such as "the whole day".